# What happens if two threads attempt to access the same variable without any locking mechanism?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety

Imagine I have a BackgroundWorker that operates on a WorkObject shared between a main thread and the worker thread.

The WorkObject contains a boolean value "IsFinished".  When the BackgroundWorker finishes its work, it sets IsFinished to true.

The main thread can periodically check IsFinished to see if the worker is done.

Is it necessary to use a synchronization mechanism to protect access to IsFinished in such a simple case like this?  Is it possible for the mainthread and worker to try to access IsFinished in exactly the same cycle and cause some sort of weird glitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

1. You only have one writer; AND
2. You do not care about false negatives (ie. isFinished appears false to the main thread while it is true to the worker thread)

Then you could get away without having synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the mainthread and worker to try to access IsFinished in exactly the same cycle and cause some sort of weird glitch?

No. Normal computer hardware serializes all memory accesses.

> Is it necessary to use a synchronization mechanism ... in such a simple case?

user2244003's answer mentioned "false negatives."

Most modern workstation and server systems, and even many mobile systems these days, have two or more CPUs, each of which has its own [memory cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)).  When one thread writes the `isFinished` variable, a number of things have to happen before another thread can see the change.  Exactly when those things happen can be different on different hardware platforms, in different operating systems and, in different implementations of your programming language's run-time support system.

In some programming languages/libraries there is a very clear specification of how the memory system must behave.  In others (e.g., in C++ prior to C++11) you were pretty much on your own to discover what worked and what didn't work.  (Including what worked and what didn't work for your customers, which could be different from what worked or not for *you*.)

Primitives that force memory updates to become visible to the threads that need to see them are called [memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).

Different languages/libraries have different ways of letting you specify memory barriers, but this rule of thumb works in most of them:  *Whatever thread A writes to memory before it unlocks some lock L will be visible to thread B after thread B locks the* same *lock L.*

Your language or library might also support some kind of [atomic data type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) for which every access has implied memory barriers.